Is this a valid notation for a directional derivative?
In Siegel (2005): Fields I found the following strange notation on page 170
$$
\frac{\partial f(\phi_i)}{\partial \phi_j} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{f(\phi_i + \epsilon \delta_{ij})-f(\phi_i)}{\epsilon}
$$
I'm especially confused about the argument $\phi_i + \epsilon \delta_{ij}$, as it looks like the author is adding a vector $\phi_i$ to a matrix $\epsilon \delta_{ij}$. Can this make sense or is this a typo? And if it is a typo, how must the expression be stated correctly?
My guess is that the author wants to write the definition of a directional derivative, and also implicitly include
$$
\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial \phi_j} = \delta_{ij}
$$
This doesn't quite fit together. But given the context (showing an discrete analog to the functional derivative) I was also not able to express that more correctly.

Is the author aiming for the Kronecker delta (1 if $i=j$, 0 if not)?

@tabstop Page 170 actually says "$\delta_{ij}$ is the usual Kronecker delta function".

This is less than ideal notation. I suggest rewriting formulas in the paper using notation you’re more comfortable with.
